# Basic electronics: input currents of multi-port sub-circuits

Tags: analog, spice, modeling, pspice

I am simulating, with PSpice, the transient behavior of an analog circuit that contains several multiport sub-circuits.
When I probe the current on all inputs of a sub-circuit, I see that the sum of all input currents is different from zero.
Is it possible or is it just a modeling issue of the sub-circuit I am analyzing? Should't the sum of all input currents be equal to zero?

[image: Simulation]

Comment: Are there hidden or implicit supply pins that you are neglecting?

Comment: @uint128_t I do not think so. I uploaded an image to show the situation.

Comment: It's definetively a (rather common) model issue. There must be some "0" nodes inside your subckt connected to the output VCVG  "minus". Please post model text if you have

Comment: @carloc the model is property of TI, however it is not encrypted and it is possible to download it from http://www.ti.com/product/TLE2426/toolssoftware

Comment: @carloc I checked the model of the sub circuit under discussion and I see that the "external" ground pin is the node number 5. Node 0 of the internal circuit is not mapped to the outside. Could it be that the difference in the current is caused by this? In general, when the internal "0" reference node is not mapped to the outside, how can I measure the real ground current from the external?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a rather common model issue. Output comes from a controlled voltage or current generator which is referenced to global "0" ground node.

Global means it doesn't have to be explicitly "taken out" of the model, "0"s are just connected each other any hierarchy level they are.

Here's an excerpt from TI model file where (5) is the external output node

> EGND   99      0   POLY(2) (3,0) (4,0) 0 .5 .5
>   ...
>   RO1   8    5   63
>   RO2   7    99  62
>   ...
>   VLIM  7    8   DC 0

This can be turn into the following schematics

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTB9Kr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, neglecting VLIM which is just a current probe to have I(VLIM) somewherelse, it is quite clear that a part (most actually)  of the output current sources/sinks from/to (0) global ground node.

That's why KCL seem to fail in your simulation. If you whish to take model's ground current into account you can just add a pin and rename all internal "0" nodes to this new connection.

All the above is a good lesson teaching **"models are just models"** they are all incomplete to some aspect. Awareness is key point in effectively using them

Answer (score -1):

If there is inductance or capacitance on the "inside" of your sub-circuit, then no, the sum of all currents doesn't need to be zero at any one time instant. Even capacitances as small as gate charge for transistors will matter at the right scales.

Comment: No, that's wrong. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws

Comment: I understand Kirshoff's law. I may have misunderstood the question. For Kirshoff's to work (sum to zero,) you have to measure and sum all inputs/outputs. If you miss one, you will get non-zero values. Or, the OP is seeing PSpice simulation artifacts; that's totally possible too.